# java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, string, data, formatação

O que está acontecendo aqui? Acho que não estou sabendo ler a documentação do [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)). Para mim essa conversão de data/hora `%td` ao receber um inteiro dentro do intervalo do dia do mês deveria funcionar.

```
class Main {  
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
            System.out.println(String.format("%td", 30));
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Integer
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printDateTime(Formatter.java:2980)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2885)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2897)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

**Edit:** Me parece que o erro está em estar passando um inteiro e não uma data. Estava trabalhando com `LocalDateTime` para exibir em formato `%td/%tm/%ty %tH:%tM:%tS`, será que funciona passar uma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na [documentação de `String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) há um link para a [sintaxe da string de formatação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). E lá é dito o seguinte:

> *The format specifiers for types which are used to represents dates and times have the following syntax:*
>
> `%[argument_index$][flags][width]conversion`

Sobre `argument_index`, falaremos mais abaixo.

`flags` e `width` são aquelas opções para alinhamento, preencher com zeros, quantidade de colunas, etc. Como você não usou, não vem ao caso. O que importa para este caso é o `conversion`.

Ainda na mesma seção sobre datas e horas, é dito que:

> *The required conversion is a two character sequence. The first character is 't' or 'T'. The second character indicates the format to be used.*

Ou seja, se tiver um "t" ou "T", é porque estamos formatando uma data/hora, e portanto o valor a ser passado deve ser um `long`, `Long`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.util.Date` ou `java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor` (interface implementada por todos os tipos de data e hora do `java.time`).

Por isso que ao usar o formato `%td`, ele dá erro quando você passa um `int`. O `t` indica que o parâmetro deveria ser um dos tipos mencionados acima (e o `d` segue a [tabela específica de "Date/Time conversions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt), que no caso indica o dia do mês).

Ou seja, se você passasse um `LocalDateTime` (que implementa `TemporalAccessor`), aí funcionaria:

```
// imprime o dia correspondente à data atual
System.out.println(String.format("%td", LocalDateTime.now()));
```

Pois o dia é extraído da data informada.

Já para imprimir mais de um campo da mesma data, é meio chato. Assim não funciona:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%td/%tm/%ty %tH:%tM:%tS", LocalDateTime.now())); // exception!
```

Pois o `%td` corresponde ao `LocalDateTime` informado, mas `%tm` refere-se ao próximo argumento (que não foi informado). Para que todos os campos se refiram à mesma data, você deve usar o `argument_index`, cuja sintaxe é `N$`, sendo que `N` corresponde à enésima data informada. Então na verdade deveria ser essa "coisa bonita":

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$td/%1$tm/%1$ty %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS", LocalDateTime.now()));
```

Mas como [você mesmo já respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492636/112052), o melhor para formatar datas e horas é usar a própria API de datas:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

Sobre o uso de `uuuu` em vez de `yyyy` para o ano, [veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418).

Comment: Jogo rápido, na documentação fala de usar `<` na string de formatação, você sabe de pronto se teria alguma utilidade nesse caso ou não tem nada a ver? Quando olhei achei por cima que era algo sobre repetir o parâmetro anterior, alguma coisa assim. Se não der para responder não tem problema (eu sei, preguiça minha, mas dizem que o importante não é saber, é ter o telefone de quem sabe kkk).

Comment: @Piovezan Esse eu nunca usei, mas pelo que entendi, também funcionaria, pois ele serve para indicar que é pra usar o mesmo argumento do anterior - ou seja, `%1$td/%<tm/%<ty` seria o mesmo que `%1$td/%1$tm/%1$ty`

Answer (score 1):

Mudei a forma de fazer, na verdade era basicamente isso que eu queria:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-01-30T09:51:38");
String formattedDateTime = DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(localDateTime);
System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

Saída:

```
30/01/2021 09:51:38
```

É uma "[solução XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/357)" (que não resolve o problema original), mas vou deixar aqui pois deverá atender alguns outros casos em que este acontecer.