# Como formatar a data e o mês para que fiquem com digito 0 em sua formatação (de dia ou mês que vai de 1 a 9)?

Tags: java, android-studio, datepicker

Estou querendo adicionar um zero no dia e mês na data que o `editData_devolucao` recebe. Tipo, em vez de aparecer dia `05` é apenas `5` e no mês ao invés de aparecer `06` aparece apenas `6`.

Exemplo:

- Como retorna: `2/6/2021`
- Como eu queria que retornasse: `02/06/2021`

A linha que corresponde a formatação de minha data é

```
String data_dev = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano; // Formatação da data atual
```

### Código

```
            EditText editData_devolucao;
            
            editData_devolucao = findViewById(R.id.editData_devolucao);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(getDefault(Category.FORMAT));
            dia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            ano = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            editData_devolucao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                            CadastrarEmprestimo.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int ano, int mes, int dia){
                            mes += 1;
                            String data_dev = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano; // Formatação da data atual
                            editData_devolucao.setText(data_dev);
                        }
                    },ano,mes,dia);
                    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Formatar data no java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231106/formatar-data-no-java) - é só adaptar o formato para o seu caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `String.format` para isso, usando o parâmetro "0nd", onde n é o número de digitos que deve ter.
Por exemplo `String.format("%02d", dia)` vai formatar "dia" para 2 digitos, completando com zero a esquerda.

Ficaria assim:

```
String data_dev = String.format("%02d", dia) + "/" + String.format("%02d", mes) + "/" + Integer.toString(ano);
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/GkfBAqR

**EDIT**: aproveitando a sugestão do @hkotsubo, fica ainda mais simples assim:  `String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", dia, mes, ano)`

Comment: `String.format` possui [formatos específicos para datas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dt) ([exemplo de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492684/112052)), e aí dá pra usar o `Calendar` direto, sem precisar pegar os campos separadamente. De qualquer forma, a melhor maneira está na dup que indiquei (usar a API de datas nativa)

Comment: sim @hkotsubo, mas esse formatos funcionam se tiver a data em  uma String ou um objeto de Data, como na pergunta cada parte da data é um valor inteiro (dia, mes e ano) não daria pra fazer usando esses formatos citados na outra resposta

Comment: Mas se for usar os campos separados, daria pra fazer tudo de uma vez: `String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", dia, mes, ano)`. Mas eu ainda prefiro a API nativa de datas :-)

Comment: "*não daria pra fazer usando esses formatos citados na outra resposta*" - Daria sim porque na pergunta ele cria um `Calendar`. A menos que o método ali só aceite os campos separados

Comment: eu vi o objeto, mas eu me orientei pelo método em si, mas a sua sugestão é muito boa, eu tentei deixar o mais próximo da pergunta mas fica bem melhor realmente, vou adicionar na resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

acho q o que vc precisa é isso aqui né:

`String strDate= String.format("%02d/%02d/%s", dia, mes, ano);`